# Character marker symbology based on a field

Tags: arcgis-desktop, symbology, unicode, ttf

I'm a bit unsure of how to express this question without being too unspecific but I hope you understand what I'm getting at...

I have a symbol library as a .ttf with geotechnical symbols. I would like the symbology to pick a symbol from the library without manually adding all the different symbols using hex or unicode values in a field.

I have found lots of information regarding applying color based on hex etc. However I have not been able to find the above example/implementation.

I know for a fact it is a possibility, at least in a web-based GIS environment. And library is based on the sum of the number of bits for each symbol translate to a hex value. I don't know if that makes any sense.

Comment: Welcome. Have you already added the font to your fonts directory as described here: https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/product/mapping/fonts-in-arcgis-symbols/ ?

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I have added the font as described. And now I want the fiels to be symbolized to specific characters in the font based on its unicode value in a fiels rather than manually setting up a lyr-file for the font.